# Philippines citizen working in Romania do I need a visa to go to Italy?

Tags: international-travel, schengen-visas, standard-visitor-visas, filipino-citizens

I'm a Filipino citizen working here in Romania. The question is if I want to travel to Italy do I need to get a visa? What are the requirements for a visa and in the airport?

Answer (score 1):

You need a visa and your passport must be less than 10 years old and valid for at least 3 months beyond the period of intended stay.

Source: Timatic, the system used by airlines https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b

Comment: All because Romania is not part of Schengen.